# Ошибка сборки файлов с функциями mem_calloc

Tags: linux, c, gcc, include, calloc

Доброго времени суток. Собираю файл из пакета John The Ripper на linux (Ubuntu 16.04), а именно [hmacSHA256_fmt_plug.c](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/src/hmacSHA256_fmt_plug.c). Подключил, вроде бы, все возможные `include`, кроме `arch.h`, который не обнаружен в сорсах. Команда выглядит следующим образом:

```
gcc -o JTR_hmac_sha256 JTR_hmac_sha256.c sha2.h aligned.h openssl_local_overrides.h misc.h jumbo.h common.h base64_convert.h formats.h params.h johnswap.h simd-intrinsics.h pseudo_intrinsics.h simd-intrinsics-load-flags.h memdbg.h os.h
```

После этого высвечиваются `warning` и `error`, в одном из которых следующее:

```
JTR_hmac_sha256.c:160:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mem_calloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  crypt_key = mem_calloc(self->params.max_keys_per_crypt,
```

Замечу, что почти все ошибки компиляции связаны с этой функцией.
Погуглив, я обнаружил, что есть функции из модуля `MEM`, а именно:
[image: MEM-module].
Вопрос такой: то ли это и если да, то что вообще необходимо подключить к файлу с кодом?

EDIT:
Заменил все функции `mem_calloc` и `MEM_FREE` на обычные `calloc` и `free`. При повторной компиляции высветилась следующая ошибка.

```
simd-intrinsics.h:131:53: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘ARCH_BITS_STR’
#define SHA256_ALGORITHM_NAME                 "32/" ARCH_BITS_STR " " SHA2_LIB
```

Не могу понять, почему тут должна стоять фигурная скобка, ведь до этой строки в файле `simd-intrinsics.h` идут точно такие же конструкции. На всякий случай привожу кусок кода, на который ругается `gcc`:

```
#if ARCH_BITS >= 64
#define SHA256_ALGORITHM_NAME                 "64/" ARCH_BITS_STR " " SHA2_LIB
#define SHA512_ALGORITHM_NAME                 "64/" ARCH_BITS_STR " " SHA2_LIB
#else
#define SHA256_ALGORITHM_NAME                 "32/" ARCH_BITS_STR " " SHA2_LIB
#define SHA512_ALGORITHM_NAME                 "32/" ARCH_BITS_STR " " SHA2_LIB
#endif
```

Comment: думаю, скорее всего ее можно заменить на обычный calloc

Comment: @KoVadim, а это как-то существенно повлияет на работу программы?

Comment: а кто его знает. Нужно смотреть исходники, понять, почему там такая функция...

Comment: @KoVadim, ну я скинул ссылку на исходники, в надежде, что более опытные пользователи помогут разобраться в этом.

Comment: я же и пишу - по тому что есть, оно должно заработать. Нужно компилировать и тестить

Comment: пробуйте. По логике это она и есть

Comment: @KoVadim, всё заменил. Теперь возникла новая проблема, посмотрите, пожалуйста, обновлённое содержание поста.

Comment: никто же  не знает, что скрывается за ARCH_BITS_STR

Comment: @KoVadim, просто очень странно, что предыдущие две строки не вызвали ничего плохого у `gcc`. Странно ещё то, что со столькими закаываками собирается один отдельный файл из всего модуля..